# Scaling percentages to calculate values on an even scale

Tags: percentages

Factory $A$ had $20$ defective items this year.
Factory $B$ has $180$ defective items this year.

However, Factory A only produced $6\%$ of the products Factory $B$ does.

We need to find the number of defective items that Factory $A$ would produce this year if they produced the same $\#$ of products as Factory $B$ did (and not only $6\%$).

How would we do this and what would the predicted number be for Factory $A$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: What piece(s) of information do you need to solve for before you can calculate the factory A's predicted number? Try to break the problem into steps. Also, it turns out that the answer is independent of the number of items Factory A produces!

Comment: I just need to treat these factories as the 'same' so they can be compared to which is doing worse despite the difference in output.